# OpenFileDialog Run two

Tags: c#

I want button6 & button2 select the file , and the start button starts the 2 selected files

[image]

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // road
{

    Stream myStream = null;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Road.Service (Road.Service.exe)|Road.Service.exe|Road.Service|Road.Service.exe";
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;



    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (myStream)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //center
{

    Stream myStream = null;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Center.Service (Center.Service.exe)|Center.Service.exe|Center.Service|Center.Service.exe";
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;



    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (myStream)
                {

                }
            }

        }


        catch
        {
        }
    }
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //start
{
    Process.Start(button6 , button2);
}
```

Comment: So whats the problem? what isn't working?

Comment: @Sayse - obviously - `Process.Start(button6 , button2);`

Comment: with the code you have presented this does nobody any good if you do not have any code within both of the `using(myStream)` are you looking for someone to provide you code..? google how to use `Process.Start` and also look up the `waituntil` method as well

Comment: @Igor - That wasn't obvious at all, all I saw was a code block (dump) without any description as to *what* the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your point.
If you want to open files in the third button the following code is your solution :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // road
{

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Road.Service (Road.Service.exe)|Road.Service.exe|Road.Service|Road.Service.exe";
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        openFileDialog1 = openFileDialog;
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //center
{

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Center.Service (Center.Service.exe)|Center.Service.exe|Center.Service|Center.Service.exe";
    openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        openFileDialog2 = openFileDialog;
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //start
{
    Stream myStream1 = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
    //...
    Stream myStream2 = openFileDialog2.OpenFile();
    //...
}

public OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 { get; set; }
public OpenFileDialog openFileDialog2 { get; set; }
```